# difficulties getting all files from a directory with sftp via shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

i'm trying to get all files from a remote server with sftp command via Linux shell script, my code is:

```
    lftp -u ${sourceEnv},${password} sftp://${Host}<<EOF
    cd $sourceBuildDir/build/64/trace/products/lib/
    get *
    bye
    EOF
```

the problem is that i get the next output when running the script:
        get: Access failed: No such file (*)

It doesn't recognize the * sign which is basically was used by me to specify that i need to get all files from that directory, i tried to quote it like '*' or "*" and it still doesn't work.
The script does work whenever i specify the full name of a file in a get command, but i need it to be more generic.
How do you think i should implement that ?
Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: you need `mget *`. It won't recurse on dirs, however, you might luck out with `mget */*, mget */*/* ...` but that sort of thing is very client version specific. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably set up passwordless, passphraseless ssh first, to avoid passing a password on the command line.  Passwords sent on the command line show up in ps, which is a security issue.

That will also make it so you can do this with a single-line scp, instead of a multiline lftp.

http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/ssh-keys.html

Comment: thanks, for the quick answer, but i have a problem in setting up a passwordless login, because those are company machines, and have problem by doing it in single scp command, because i have to get to multiple directories on that machine and get files from there, so i thought that opening an sftp connection will be much more efficient.